# Complete missing outcrop problem

Tags: geology, homework, mapping, topography, cartography

Given A is upper limit of sand stone, B is the lower limit of the planes that are equal in distance and dip. Dip angle is 29 degrees.

Complete the outcrop of this map.

—————————————————————————-

Now I know that strike lines should go in height 400

But there are 3 points so how could that even be possible.

2 of these points are on strike line but what about the third?

I really don’t know how to approach this question

Also from dip angle I can easily find the distance from each strike line but that is for later
[image]

Comment: What does the text at the bottom of your image say?

Comment: Given In the map above the upper limit A and the lower limit B of sand stone layer , you have to complete the limits of this layer the upper and the lower in all over the map , the dip of all layers is constant and the thickness between them is constant , you have all the information to solve the question . Additional information : ( dip angle 28 degrees )

Comment: I have translated it accordingly

Comment: In the map upper left Scale 1:10000 cm

Answer (score 3):

[image]

First step - draw a strike line where line A intersects the 400 m line.

Second step - you know that the sandstone layer is of equal thickness and dip, so you can draw a parallel line at the place with line B intersects the 400 m line. This will give you the thickness, as expressed on a horizontal surface. You know what the dip angle is, so getting the real thickness is simple trigonometry.

This should get you started.

Comment: Can you add more hints , after getting the thickness What should I do ? Probably getting the other strike lines from that thickness but how

Comment: @Mather each strike line will be equispaced, so it's just a matter of finding where each strike intersects its respective altitude line.

Comment: Can you show that on the map , for example if the thickness is ,  t = 5 cm , where should I draw strike line 500 , 600 . 5 cm from the right of strike line 400 at A ? Or to the left ? Or at B ? 

So many options

Comment: I feel like I should put strike at B-500 , then using the distance from A400 to B400 , I can also say it’s the same distance from A500 to B-500 , without calculating the thickness

Comment: I don’t think the thickness is important , only the measured distance on the map , this distance is constant and so I can say B500 and A500 is at the same distance and so I can find A500

Comment: Then I can say the distance from A400 to A500 is constant and conclude A600 A700 and so on . The dip angle here is not important

Comment: But I thought about it , the lines you put on the graph , there distance should be constant between each hight for example if we measure 5 cm distance on the map between A400 to B400 then also it should be 5cm from A500 to B500 right ?

Comment: @Mather you have the place where line B intersects line 500. It's a bit to the right of my red line "2". This is the horizontal distance between strike lines. It is the same distance for the top and the bottom of the layer.

Comment: It’s the same distance for all strike lines at bottom layers This is true , but why also at top layers

Comment: The distance between the purple lines = the distance between the red And your claim that from top and bottom layers the distance between red and purple line is the same right ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmgF2.jpg

Comment: Anyway the dip angle could be useful to see if I answered the question right by calculating it using the draw i think that’s why they gave us the dip angle it’s like hidden solution